# Golang yaml generation double entries

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I want to generate the following in yaml:

```
- bar: hello
- bar: another
  pint: guiness

- bar: second
  pint: ""
```

in Golang, however making the following example, I get the output below:

```
- bar:
  - bar: hello
  - bar: another
  pint: guiness
- bar:
  - bar: second
  pint: ""
```

It seems the YAML Golang parser puts the names of the structs in the YAML it generates like `- bar:` and then the member array under it.  I don't want that, as it will break other things.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "log"
)

type bar struct {
    Bar string
}

type foo struct {
    Bars []bar  `yaml:"bar"`
    Pint string `yaml:"pint"`
}

func main() {
    f := make([]foo, 2)
    f[0].Bars = make([]bar, 2)
    f[0].Bars[0].Bar = "hello"
    f[0].Bars[1].Bar = "another"
    f[0].Pint = "guiness"
    f[1].Bars = make([]bar, 1)
    f[1].Bars[0].Bar = "second"

    y, err := yaml.Marshal(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Marshal: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(y))
}
```

I wondered if there is a way to get it to generate it like the first example?

Even if it means I have to use another YAML library.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.*

Comment: `foo.Bars` should be a string, not a slice.

Comment: @Peter I want an array of `bar` structs tho.  This is a simplified example, but essentially I need to have an array of structs and would really like it not to print the outer struct name.

Comment: That's not what you show in the desired output. There the bar fields are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type T struct {
    Bar  string `yaml:"bar,omitempty"`
    Pint string `yaml:"pint,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var t = make([]T, 3)
    t[0].Bar = "hello"

    t[1].Bar = "another"
    t[1].Pint = "guiness"

    t[2].Bar = "second"

    y, err := yaml.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Marshal: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(y))
}
```

Output:

```
- bar: hello
- bar: another
  pint: guiness
- bar: second
```

If you want to keep the empty string like in your desired output then you can do this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type S string

func (s *S) IsZero() bool {
    return false
}

type T struct {
    Bar  string `yaml:"bar,omitempty"`
    Pint *S     `yaml:"pint,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var t = make([]T, 3)
    t[0].Bar = "hello"

    t[1].Bar = "another"
    p1 := S("guiness")
    t[1].Pint = &p1

    t[2].Bar = "second"
    p2 := S("")
    t[2].Pint = &p2

    y, err := yaml.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Marshal: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(y))
}
```

Output:

```
- bar: hello
- bar: another
  pint: guiness
- bar: second
  pint: ""
```

More info on yaml package: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2